# How do I sum values from one column dependent on items in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Course  Orders Ingredient 1 Ingredient 2  Ingredient 3
    starter 3      Fish         Bread         Mayonnaise
    starter 1      Olives       Bread   
    starter 5      Hummus       Pita    
    main    1      Pizza        
    main    6      Beef         Potato        Peas
    main    9      Fish         Peas    
    main    11     Bread        Mayonnaise    Beef
    main    4      Pasta        Bolognese     Peas
    desert  10     Cheese       Olives        Crackers
    desert  7      Cookies      Cream   
    desert  8      Cheesecake   Cream
```

I would like to sum the number of orders for each ingredient per course. It is not important which column the ingredient is in.

The following dataframe is what I would like my output to be:

```
Course  Ord Ing1       IngOrd1 Ing2     IngOrd2 Ing3 IngOrd3
starter 3   Fish       3       Bread    4       Mayo     3
starter 1   Olives     1       Bread    4       
starter 5   Hummus     5       Pita     5       
main    1   Pizza      1                
main    6   Beef       17      Potato   6       Peas     21
main    9   Fish       9       Peas     21      
main    11  Bread      11      Mayo     11      Beef     17
main    4   Pasta      4       Bolognese 4      Peas     21
desert  10  Cheese     10      Olives   10      Crackers 10
desert  7   Cookies    7       Cream    15      
desert  8   Cheesecake 8       Cream    15
```

I have tried using groupby().sum() but this does not work with the ingredients in 3 columns.

I also cannot use lookup because there are instances in the full dataframe where I do not know what ingredient I am looking for.

Comment: Could you please explain how you are computing IngOrd1, 2, 3 columns?

Comment: @trollster Those columns are summations of orders that require specific ingredient.  For example, in Ingredient1 column "Beef" has six orders, in Ingredient2 Beef has 0 orders, and in Ingredient3 Beef has 11 orders: hence IngOrd1 and IngOrd3 have a value of 17 for Beef.  I understand HOW he is summing, I just do not understand why Hamish wants the dataframe displayed and organized in this way.  I think there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: @Hamish Pegg It would be helpful to provide a working example that we can run locally and play with.  Generally a good practice.

Comment: @tnknepp Going by that logic, Olives must be 11 right under IngOrd2? And how is Peas or Blognese being computed?

Comment: @trollster I admit defeat!  You are correct.  I only considered a few items within the dataframe.  I still do not understand why Hamish wants the data represented in such a convoluted manner.  Alas, I doubt we will ever hear back from him.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's really slick way to this with groupby or other such pandas methods, though I'm happy to be proven wrong. In any case, the following is not especially pretty, but it will give you what you're after.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

# The data you provided
df = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')

# Group these labels for convenience
ingredients = ['Ingredient 1', 'Ingredient 2', 'Ingredient 3']
orders = ['IngOrd1', 'IngOrd2', 'IngOrd3']

# Interleave the two lists for final data frame
combined = [y for x in zip(ingredients, orders) for y in x]

# Restructure the data frame so we can group on ingredients
melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Course', 'Orders'], value_vars=ingredients, value_name='Ingredient')

# This is a map that we can apply to each ingredient column to
# look up the correct order count
maps = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

# Build the map. Every course/ingredient pair is keyed to the total
# count for that pair, e.g. {(main, beef): 17, ...}
for index, group in melted.groupby(['Course', 'Ingredient']):
    course, ingredient = index
    maps[course][ingredient] += group.Orders.sum()

# Now apply the map to each ingredient column of the data frame
# to create the new count columns
for i, o in zip(ingredients, orders):
    df[o] = df.apply(lambda x: maps[x.Course][x[i]], axis=1)

# Adjust the columns labels
df = df[['Course', 'Orders'] + combined]

print df

     Course  Orders Ingredient 1  IngOrd1 Ingredient 2  IngOrd2 Ingredient 3  IngOrd3
0   starter       3         Fish        3        Bread        4   Mayonnaise        3
1   starter       1       Olives        1        Bread        4          NaN        0
2   starter       5       Hummus        5         Pita        5          NaN        0
3      main       1        Pizza        1          NaN        0          NaN        0
4      main       6         Beef       17       Potato        6         Peas       19
5      main       9         Fish        9         Peas       19          NaN        0
6      main      11        Bread       11   Mayonnaise       11         Beef       17
7      main       4        Pasta        4    Bolognese        4         Peas       19
8    desert      10       Cheese       10       Olives       10     Crackers       10
9    desert       7      Cookies        7        Cream       15          NaN        0
10   desert       8   Cheesecake        8        Cream       15          NaN        0
```

You'll need to handle the NaNs and 0 counts if that's an issue. But that's a trivial task.